# React Router Path with Repeating Regex to allow for unlimited url parameters

Tags: reactjs, regex, react-router

I'm trying to create inifinite possibilities for keys and values using `react-router`.
I'm trying the following, at a url of `http://localhost:8080/search-cars/?this=that&thisses=thates` but am printing out only empty objects

```
<Route path={`{links.myPage}/(:key=:value)*`} component={myPage} />
```

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const MyPage = ({ match }) => {
    console.log(useParams())
    console.log(match.params)
```

---

[Here is a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-einstein-rfonx?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: What are url parameters? Are you referring to Query String parameters? `localhost:8080:/rootPath/key1=value1/key2=value2` doesn't look like a valid URL.

Comment: @DrewReese that might be what they’re called

Comment: `match.params` are the URL parameters set in the path. Query string parameters will be in `location` [search object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location).